# Could someone clarify this code snippet for me?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, export-to-csv

This piece should create a csv file. The method that is calling to the nonAjaxPost is:

```
function exportCSV()
{
    nonAjaxPost('getExport', 'post', {action: '/getView', 'view': current_pi, 'parameters': encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(current_parameters))});
}

function nonAjaxPost(action, method, input) {
    "use strict";
    var form;
    form = $('<form />', {
        action: action,
        method: method,
        style: 'display: none;'
    });
    if (typeof input !== 'undefined') {
        $.each(input, function (name, value) {
            $('<input />', {
                type: 'hidden',
                name: name,
                value: value
            }).appendTo(form);
        });
    }
    form.appendTo('body').submit();
}
```

My problem is that i just can't seem to understand how this is going to create a csv file for me. I'm probaly missing out on something that i just can't see.

I really hope someone could help me out.

**Update:**

This is the getExport function:

```
$databundle = $this->_getData();
    $data = $databundle['rows'];
    $columns_all = $databundle['columns'];

    $columns = array("Id");
    foreach($data[0] as $key => $column) {
        $column = "";
        $found = false;
        foreach($columns_all as $col_search) {
            if($col_search['key'] == @$key) {
                $found = true;
                $column = $col_search['title'];
                break;
            }
        }
        if($found) {
            //echo $key . ",";
            $columns[] = $column;
        }
    }   

    $contents = putcsv($columns, ';', '"');

    foreach($data as $key => $vals) {
        if(isset($vals['expand'])) {
            unset($vals['expand']);
        }

        array_walk($vals, '__decode');
        $contents .= putcsv($vals,';', '"');
    }


    $response = Response::make($contents, 200);
    $response->header("Last-Modified",gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
    $response->header("Content-type","text/x-csv");
    $response->header("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=".str_replace(" ","_",$databundle['title'])."_".date("Y-m-d_H:i").".csv");        

    return $response;
```

It also calls the getData function which is this:

```
$viewClass = str_replace('/', '', (isset($_POST['view']) ? $_POST['view'] : $_GET['view']));

    $fileView = '../app/classes/view.'.$viewClass.'.php';
    if(file_exists($fileView))
    {
        require_once($fileView);
        $className = 'view_'.$viewClass;
        if(class_exists($className))
        {
            $view = new $className();

            //Seek for parameters
            if(isset($_REQUEST['parameters']))
            {
                //Decode parameters into array
                $parameters = json_decode(urldecode((isset($_POST['parameters']) ? $_POST['parameters'] : $_GET['parameters'])),true);

                //Get supported parameters
                $parameterTypes = $view->getVars();

                $vars = array();
                foreach($parameterTypes as $key => $type)
                {
                    //If a value is found for a supported parameter in $_GET
                    if(isset($parameters[$key]))
                    {
                        switch($type)
                        {
                            case 'int':
                                $vars[$key] = intval($parameters[$key]);
                                break;
                            case 'float':
                                $vars[$key] = floatval($parameters[$key]);
                                break;
                            case 'filterdata':
                                // todo: date validation
                                $vars[$key] = $parameters[$key];
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }

                $view->setVars($vars);
            }

            return $view->getData();
        }
        else {
            /*
            header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error');
            echo 'Class ' . $className . ' does not exist.';
            */
            return false;
        }
    }
    else {
        /*
        header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
        die('Cannot locate view (' . $fileView . ').');
        */
        return false;
```

I hope this is sufficient.

In short what i am trying to find out is that the csv that it produces has more columns than columns headers and where the difference comes from

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that the page you are calling (on the server) is generating the CSV file.

You would need to write code on the server to do the conversion.

Answer (score 0):

This method is making a post request  to getView page. Your csv create code would be present on getView page.

Answer (score 0):

This is the front end code that creates an invisible form with your data: `current_parameters`.

See the content of `current_parameters` in the the current file.

Review back-end code and look for the `"getExport"` function (it should be the current php file loaded)

If you just copied this function from some example... you have to add also the back-end code on your own.

**Update**:

look at the getExport code:

```
$contents = putcsv($columns, ';', '"');

$contents .= putcsv($vals,';', '"');;
```

First row insert the titles , and the second loops the data and insert the other rows.
Print the content of `$columns` and `$vals` and see what is happening.
There are some strange conditions for filtering the columns... but can help you if you don't show the data you try to parse.

Comment: See that was allready 1 thing i couldn't see. I added the getExport function which also calls to the getData function which i also included.